# Mouse not working on MacBook Pro M1

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, mouse, monterey, apple-silicon

I have a USB Fujitsu mouse (Blue LED Mouse M960) which refuses to work with my MacBook Pro 2021 with the M1 chip (MacOS version 12.6.1).

When executing `ioreg -p IOUSB -l -w 0`:

```
  | +-o Fujitsu Mouse M960@01100000  <class IOUSBHostDevice, id 0x1002c6a11, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (60 ms), retain 34>
  |     {
  |       "sessionID" = 69335149141702
  |       "USBSpeed" = 1
  |       "idProduct" = 4155
  |       "iManufacturer" = 0
  |       "bDeviceClass" = 0
  |       "IOPowerManagement" = {"PowerOverrideOn"=Yes,"CapabilityFlags"=32768,"MaxPowerState"=2,"DevicePowerState"=2,"DriverPowerState"=0,"ChildrenPowerState"=2,"CurrentPowerState"=2}
  |       "bcdDevice" = 276
  |       "bMaxPacketSize0" = 64
  |       "iProduct" = 2
  |       "iSerialNumber" = 0
  |       "bNumConfigurations" = 1
  |       "USB Product Name" = "Fujitsu Mouse M960"
  |       "USB Address" = 1
  |       "locationID" = 17825792
  |       "bDeviceSubClass" = 0
  |       "bcdUSB" = 512
  |       "kUSBCurrentConfiguration" = 1
  |       "IOCFPlugInTypes" = {"9dc7b780-9ec0-11d4-a54f-000a27052861"="IOUSBHostFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOUSBLib.bundle"}
  |       "bDeviceProtocol" = 0
  |       "USBPortType" = 0
  |       "IOServiceDEXTEntitlements" = (("com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.usb"))
  |       "Device Speed" = 1
  |       "idVendor" = 3064
  |       "kUSBProductString" = "Fujitsu Mouse M960"
  |       "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
  |       "kUSBAddress" = 1
  |     }
```

I can see it is recognised correctly and also the mouse looks like it's powered at least (LEDs and sensor turned on) but the pointer does not move and all buttons do not react.

On other PCs it's working just fine.

Comment: Did you try different ports?

Comment: Is it wired or wireless?  If wired, are you connecting through a hub or USB-C to USB-A converter?  Have you tried a different port?

Comment: It may be that beast that is A Mouse That Requires A Driver. Does Fujitsu offer a Mac driver anywhere on their website? Failing that there are third party mouse/usb drivers that often work with mice that don't have native support from the Manufacturer like USB Overdrive and others.

Comment: I tried different ports with different adapters. Turned out that the mouse is not compatible (out-of-the-box) with MacOS. Other mice work.
The "problematic" mouse works under Windows and Linux without any additional driver. So it's detected; some generic driver should be able to use that mouse (at least the basic functions). Ideas?